# How to sum last 3 months by looping through a list in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values for each month 1 to 12 in excel. When the quarter ends in December then it should sum the values for the quarter Oct, Nov, and Dec i.e. Month  10, 11, and 12. The current function used is an offset function
`=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX($F$999:$F$1008,MATCH(MONTH($B1013),$E$999:$E$1008)),0,0,-3,1))`.The formula works well when the starting position is Mar, Jun, Sep, and December. However, assume the quarter ending month is Jan. Then using the above function will only sum values for Jan because above that there are no values 2 months prior.

**Desired outcome**: If the quarter ends in Jan then it should loop through the list and sum Nov, Dec, and Jan. The goal is to perform a sensitivity analysis because the quarter ending month can be any month, and based on the quarter ending month it will sum up all the values for the quarter.

The list is given below, so if the quarter ends in Feb it should sum (Dec) 10% + (Jan) 3% + (Feb) 6% = 19%

```
Jan 1   3%
Feb 2   6%
Mar 3   2%
Apr 4   9%
May 5   5%
Jun 6   8%
Jul 7   3.2%
Aug 8   12%
Sep 9   6.5%
Oct 10  5.6%
Nov 11  8%
Dec 12  10%
```

Comment: what version of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The **trick** is to generate a numeric sequence that will match the required months.

Note that, in your table, the month number = the index into the table.

A formula that will generate the required sequence, such that if you the quarter ending month is January (eg month number 1) => `{11,12,1}` is

```
  Office 365:  =SUM(INDEX(monthly,MOD(SEQUENCE(3, ,F2+12-2)-1,12)+1,3))
  
  older versions:  =MOD(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,3))+F2+12-4,12)+1
```

where `F2` contains the month number of the ending quarter.

So for O365:

```
=SUM(INDEX(monthly,MOD(SEQUENCE(3, ,F2+12-2)-1,12)+1,3))

  or      :  =SUM(XLOOKUP(MOD(SEQUENCE(3, ,F2+12-2)-1,12)+1,monthly[monthNum],monthly[perCent]))
```

where `monthly` is the name of your table

[image]

For earlier versions, try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(monthly,MOD(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,3))+F2+12-4,12)+1,3))
```

or even:

```
=SUM(INDEX(monthly,N(IF(1,MOD(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,3))+F2+12-4,12)))+1,3))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*